# Was Deadpool always aware of the fourth wall?

Tags: marvel, deadpool

We all know that Deadpool is notorious for breaking the fourth wall and that he knows he is in a comic book (or video game for that matter), but was it always like this?

Did Deadpool gain this power or was he breaking the fourth wall before becoming the *merc with the mouth*?

The answer can be from any storyline or from any writer.

Comment: Him being Wade Wilson isn't even solid canon; he may have always been the merc with a mouth, only sans the merc profession -- you know, insane. Different writers seem to handle him differently.

Comment: @Axelrod really? Isn't the movie coming out in February based on his origin story?

Comment: Are you asking if he has always been written to as being aware, or if the character in-universe, has always been aware? Deadpool, as a character, didn't always break the fourth wall. When he first showed up in New Mutants, he was just a sarcastic merc. It wasn't until later that they started doing the fourth wall breaking. I'm not sure if it was retconned to being something he did earlier in life though.

Comment: @phantom42 I'm asking for the character in universe.

Comment: It's just the nature of comics. Some writers make him a crazy guy who just wanted to be a mercenary, some make him ex-US military, some make him Canadian, etc. They're all different canons.

Comment: So basically it was never adressed?

Comment: No, it was addressed. The answer is just different depending on which writer you are asking about.

Comment: @DJClayworth I edited the question. It can be from any storyline or writer :). I'm just curious on how it would be explained other than "it's like that".

Comment: the writers already confirmed [that deadpool will break the fourth wall in the movie](http://www.bleedingcool.com/2015/11/03/deadpool-writers-confirm-movie-will-break-the-fourth-wall/)

Comment: @phantom42: The question is asking if Wade Wilson breaks the 4th wall prior to becoming Deadpool. Having said that, he appears to already do that in the released trailers.

Comment: I was happy that there ended up being way more to the 4th wall breaking than came across in the original adverts. If it had been more subtle, people who weren't really fans may not have gotten the Green Lantern remark. Great movie...THANK you Mr Reynolds for being such a pain in the arse about this movie! :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The trailer for the new Deadpool movie appears to have Wade Wilson, prior to becoming Deadpool, break the 4th wall. In it, Wade is being taken to his "procedure" on a gurney when he says, "And please don't make the super suit green. Or animated!" The "Or animated!" portion seems to clearly break the 4th wall, as it makes it a clear reference to Ryan Reynolds's previous work in *Green Lantern*, while making pretty much no sense to the other characters in-universe.

Comment: Provided that wasn't just a gag made specifically for the trailer and the scene is actually in the movie.

Comment: @BMWurm: I considered it. If the movie comes out and the line isn't in it, I'll certain edit or delete this. At the very least, I'd expect the community to respond appropriately. But until it does, this seems pretty credible.

Comment: It is, hence +1. :D

Comment: I like this! This does show that the Wade Wilson of this universe is breaking the fourth wall. I just wish we had an explanation as to WHY he breaks it.

Comment: How can we be sure that that referencing to another movie is an example of breaking the fourth wall? Wade was talking with doctors, not with us!

Comment: @Schullz: He may have been engaged in a, err, "conversation" with the "doctors", but the line about the animated suit was clearly for the benefit of the audience. Wikipedia: "Speaking directly to, otherwise acknowledging or doing something to the audience through this imaginary wall – or, in film, television, and video games, through a camera – is known as 'breaking the fourth wall'." The animated suit line acknowledges that the audience is most likely familiar with his work as Green Lantern, which Reynolds himself rated poorly.

Answer (score 3):

According to [his entry in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool), Deadpool's first appearance ever was in comics, in 1991:

> Created by artist/writer Rob Liefeld and writer Fabian Nicieza, Deadpool made his first appearance in the pages of The New Mutants #98 cover dated February 1991.

But breaking the fourth wall did not happen for most of that decade:

> In 1997, Deadpool was given his own ongoing title, initially written by Joe Kelly (...) Reportedly Kelly introduced the fourth wall breaking gimmick.

So for the first six years of publication, he could only break up to the third wall.

Just as a curiosity, crossing the info from Wikipedia with the info on [this CBR article](https://www.cbr.com/deadpool-fourth-wall-breaking-villain/) indicates that the  first time Deadpool broke the 4th wall was in the last panel of this page in Deadpool #0:

[image: A comig page from Deadpool #0]
<sup>Source: the same link as above, https://www.cbr.com/deadpool-fourth-wall-breaking-villain/</sup>

Deadpool first appearance in videogames was in [X-Men Legends II: Rise of Apocalypse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_Legends_II:_Rise_of_Apocalypse), from 2005. He had long been an expert in 4th wall demolitions by then and does break the 4th all in this game. In fact this is the media where he goes the farthest through 4th walls; in at least one game (Marvel vs. Capcom 3) he will go as far as grabbing his own life bar and wielding it as a blunt weapon against his opponents.

And then there are the Fox movies. He was not breaking any 4th walls in [2009 *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_Origins:_Wolverine), but when he did get [his own movie in 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_(film)) his previous Hollywood incarnation got retconned into not being the official one. In the 2016 movie, he is never seen breaking the 4th wall in the flashbacks of his life before getting his mutation activated - so it seems like an acquired power.

Las but not least: he was never the first Marvel character to blatantly break the 4th wall. [She-Hulk had been doing it since 1989](https://www.fandom.com/articles/she-hulk-mcu-deadpool), but she never got as much love as Deadpool. I remember other characters doing it too, but this is all I can find a reference for right now.

Comment: One of the stingers to *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* had his decapitated head wink to the camera, so there was a little fourth-wall breaking.

Answer (score -1):

While others may vary, id say most likely not. The green lantern reference in the movie was a reference FOR the audience, but plenty of previous movies have had easter eggs.

They also had a line about ryan reynolds (and his "superior acting talent" and good looks), which would denote that deadpool takes place in a universe where the merc has a celebrity unaffiliated with the actor portraying him in our world. That is to say, deadpool is aware he's in a movie (and thus most likely knows he has an actor portraying him), and he acknowledges ryan as an actor in HIS world, even if he is (or isnt) aware of ryan playing him in ours. Ergo, we could assume that *deadpool* was referencing the in-universe green lantern movie.

Sorry for the roundabout answer, but my take is basically: no. The line about ryan and the green super suit are just easter eggs. Before his cancer cure (in the movie), he wasnt aware of the 4th wall. Or at least, he didnt show it. So we could assume that the healing factor that cured his cancer also "cured" his lack of self-awareness, allowing him to look directly at the camera, as he is known to do.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You seem to be arguing against the premise of the question solely on the basis of the movie, but the question covers the comics as well.  So even if Deadpool didn't break the 4th wall in the movie, it's fairly well documented that he does (currently) in the comics.  So when did he start?

Comment: We also know that Ryan Reynolds exists in-universe because of one of the time-travel tricks Deadpool does in *Deadpool 2* where he meets Ryan Reynolds. Briefly. Violently.